# folder permission in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have problem in setup my SVN. My problem is due to permission issue I guess.
I want to give below permission to my users.

[image]

I used below script for my permission:

```
[groups]
ROLE_ADMIN = Bab
ROLE_DEV = Fah, Fir

[/]
* = r
@ROLE_ADMIN = rw

[/Illustrate/branches]
* = rw

[/Illustrate/tags]
* = r
@ROLE_ADMIN = rw

[/Illustrate/trunk]
@ROLE_ADMIN = rw
```

Then I am tring to check these permissions by using TotoiseSVN. The problem is when I am going to Branches folder with my admin and developer user I cannot create any new folder.

### Also I have same problem with admin user in tag and trunk folder. I receive below error.

### TortoiseSVN

### Access to '/svn/illustrate/!svn/txr/9-m/branches/Illustrate/testfolder' forbidden

### OK

****Please note that when I replace my permission to

```
[/]
* = rw
```

I can create new folder.
Would you mind help me to solve my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this situation `Illustrate` is the repo name. Instead of `[/Illustrate/branches]` use `[Illustrate:/branches]`. Try the following:

> [groups]
>
> ROLE_ADMIN = Bab
>
> ROLE_DEV = Fah,Fir
>
> [/]
>
> @ROLE_ADMIN = rw
>
> [Illustrate:/branches]
>
> @ROLE_DEV = rw
>
> @ROLE_ADMIN = rw
>
> [Illustrate:/tags]
>
> @ROLE_DEV = r
>
> @ROLE_ADMIN = rw
>
> [Illustrate:/trunk]
>
> @ROLE_DEV = r
>
> @ROLE_ADMIN = rw

Comment: I am receiving this message: Unable to connect to a repository at URL..... I am using SubversionEdge. when I change [/]@role_admin = rw to [/] * = r  I can access to the repository.